# Android display buttons when clicked on main button

Tags: java, android, button, click, display

I have an activity where I have a few main buttons which should be displayed all the time, and I have for every main button a few sub-buttons. The sub-buttons shall be displayed when I click on one main-button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfILe.png)

They are like titles: There are main titles and every main title has got a few sub titles. But the sub-titles should only be displayed when I click on the button with the main title. So when I dont click, only the main buttons shall be seen, not the subbuttons.
How do I realize that? Or is there a godd tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of an `View.OnClickListener()`, use the following code to make a button invisible:
`b.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

And to show it:
`b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: nice, thats a good start. Then I have to figure out, how the buttons can be moved

Comment: What do you mean move? You didn't mention this in your original question. Maybe `setTranslationX(float translationX)` and `setTranslationY(float translationY)` will work?

Comment: I meant : when 1st main button is clicked then subbottons appear and all the other main buttons move downwards.

Comment: You can probably use `setTranslationY(float translationY)` for that, although you might consider using a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner) instead.